# Type error: Property 'role' does not exist on type {...}, implementing role based auth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma, next-auth

Following [role-based-login-strategy](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/role-based-login-strategy) article, i ran into an issue:

```js
//components/Auth.tsx:35:31
--
Type error: Property 'role' does not exist on type '{ name?: string; email?: string; image?: string; }'
```

Typescript is yelling on `if (session && session.user.role === 'Admin')` at `.role` property.
Anybody, how do i bypass this issue? I  modified local node modules rules, but in production it still won't allow :(

Bellow i provided my implementations from that article.

My schema:

```js
enum Role {
  SimpleUser
  Moderator
  Admin
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  role          Role      @default(SimpleUser)
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}
```

```js
///pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js
import { NextApiHandler } from 'next'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma'

const authHandler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => NextAuth(req, res, options)
export default authHandler

const options = {
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.role = user.role
      return session
    },
  },
}
```

[expected types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2H8P.png)

Comment: if the field doesnt exist in the type, why are you trying to modify it?

if you want to add new properties to a type  you can just mape the result to a new type, augmenting with what ever additional properties you need

Comment: @Damian Green yes, the problem was i didn't know what to extend and how to import it. solution is something like
```ts
enum Role {
  SimpleUser = 'SimpleUser',
  Moderator = 'Moderator',
  Admin = 'Admin'
}

declare module 'next-auth' {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      role: Role
    } & DefaultSession['user']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the official Next Auth documentation tells us.
We can “ Extend default interface properties”
In your case, you can extend the Session interface
(which contains the user property you want to change) by following.

Create a folder on the root level named “types” and then create a file inside that folder and name it `next-auth.d.ts.`
So the path look like this `types/next-auth.d.ts`
Then paste this code:

```
import NextAuth, { DefaultSession } from "next-auth"
 
declare module "next-auth" {
  /**
   * Returned by `useSession`, `getSession` and received as a prop on the `SessionProvider` React Context
   */
  interface Session {
    user: {
      role: string | undefined | null
    } & DefaultSession["user"]
  }
}
```

Define your types inside the user property like  `role: string | undefined | null.`

Read more about "[Extend default interface properties](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#extend-default-interface-properties)" in NextAuth.